# get +1 date timestamp or for google plus activities/posts

Tags: google-plus, google-analytics-api

I am trying to get some information about the post people do in google plus. In particular I am interested in the "+1"'s.

Either from the google api or directly from the google plus web site you can get the total count and name of the people who did "+1". But, I would be interested in getting the time or timestamp of the "+1"'s. Does anyone knows if it is possible or how can I do that?

Help is always appreciated
Thanks to all,

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities, the only data we return for a +1 is a list of the +1-ers, as well as the total number of people who +1'ed the item you are looking at.

If you would like to request additional data, please file a feature request in our Issue Tracker: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list. It would really help if you could be as detailed as possible in the type of data you would like to see and how you would ideally use that data.

Comment: Of note, you could manually track the +1 clicks from +1 buttons on your website using the callback method for the +1 button but you would not get the details from +1 interactions within the Google+ stream.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with your own website and only care about +1s for pages on your own domain, you could use [Google Analytic's social information](http://analytics.blogspot.nl/2011/06/1-reporting-in-google-webmaster-tools.html) to see how +1s change over time. You wouldn't get information about who did the +1ing.